# Open Link in New Tab Logo LaTex

Tags: latex, icons, pdflatex

I have been looking all over the internet and have yet to find a solution to my problem. I am creating a resume from LaTex and would like to add an "open link" button

[image: 1]

I was wondering if anyone had code that shows the button or any resources that can help me find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the `hyperref` and `fontawesome5` packages to create such a link:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\href{https://topanswers.xyz/tex}{\faExternalLink*}

\end{document}
```

[image]